# How can I get list of items from existing database and view it on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i added my existing database.db file to my project with sqflite [Open an asset database](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md)
(I added this to my `db_helper.dart` file inside `initializeDB()` function.)
No errors encountered, everything works fine, but...
I want to list items but how can i fetch data from database table to ListView?
Which functions must be added to `db_helper.dart` and how can i call them from `main.dart`?

Here is the model `Country.dart` file:

```dart
class Countries {
  int _id;
  String _countryName;
  String _image;

  //Constructor
  Countries(this._id, this._countryName, this._image);

  //Gettters
  int get id => _id;
  String get name => _countryName;
  String get image => _image;

  // Extract a Product Object from a Map Oject
  Countries.fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map['country_id'];
    this._countryName = map['country_name'];
    this._image = map['image'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a function in your db_helper.dart file to conduct the query and convert the results to your model.

```
 Future<List<Countries>> getCountries() async {
    List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Countries');
    return list.map((countries) => Countries.fromMapObject(countries)).toList();
  }
```

Then you can initialize your database from your main.dart and then run the query in a future builder.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Initialize class in db_helper.dart file and initialize Database
  final dbHelper = DBHelper()
  @override
  void initState() {
    dbHelper.initializeDB();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //close Database Connection
    dbHelper.closeDB();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<Countries>(
        future: dbHelper.getCountries(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              ListTile(leading: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].image),title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),)
            },
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```